# Testing with Tinytest exceptions

Tags: meteor, exception, tinytest, meteor-packages

I am working on unit test using Tinytest in a package and I wanted to test that a method raise an exception and I can test it using `test.throws()`.

I create a meteor project :

```
meteor create myapp
cd myapp
meteor add tinytest
```

To create a package, I do

```
meteor create --package test-exception
```

---

And this is my simple test
File `test-exception.js`

```
Joe = {
    init: function () {
        throw "an exception";
    }
}
```

File `package.js`

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'tinytest-throws',
  version: '0.0.1'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.0.2');
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.addFiles('tinytest-throws.js');

  api.export('Joe', 'server'); // create a global variable for the server side
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('tinytest-throws');
  api.addFiles('tinytest-throws-tests.js', 'server'); // launch this test only as server
});
```

File `test-exception-tests.js`

```
Tinytest.add('Call a method that raise an exception', function (test) {
    test.throws(
        Joe.init, // That could be a way, but this fails
        "This is an exception"
    );

    test.throws(
        Joe.init(),
        "This is an exception"
    );
});
```

Does somebody know how to test that exceptions are well raised ?

Comment: What's wrong with a `try catch` block?

Comment: I don't know if there are `test.ok()` and `test.fail()` withTinytest (no trace in the cookbook : https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/writing.unit.tests.md#tinytest-api) and I do not want to use `test.isTrue(true)` while `test.throws()` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I get it.
First, you have to use Meteor.Error. So my `Joe` object becomes :

```
Joe = {
    init: function () {
        throw new Meteor.Error("This is an exception");
    }
}
```

Now, I can catch the error using `Test.throws` :

```
test.throws(
    function() {
        Joe.init()
    },
    "n except" // a substring of the exception message
);
```